# Share an image shows only two option, Mail and Onenote

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am trying to share an image locally and I am retrieving it like this
[image]

But If I called the

```
DataTransferManager.ShowShareUI();
```

I only get two options. But in Photos application, when I share a photo, I see all the compatible apps for it, like Instagram. But my app has only two.
[image]

Any idea how to get all the option like this?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your code is sharing only the actual bitmap:

```
req.data.SetBitmap(rasr)
```

Of the apps you have installed only Mail and OneNote know what to do with the bitmap. This is fairly common, and many share targets will accept a [bitmap file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br205913) but not a bitmap itself. See [How to share files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh871371.aspx)

```
// Because we are making async calls in the DataRequested event handler,
// we need to get the deferral first.
DataRequestDeferral deferral = req.GetDeferral();  

// Make sure we always call Complete on the deferral.
try
{
    StorageFile logoFile = 
        await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("Assets\\beautiful_folder\\and_a_beautiful_file.jpg");
    List<IStorageItem> storageItems = new List<IStorageItem>();
    storageItems.Add(logoFile);
    req.Data.SetStorageItems(storageItems);       
}
finally
{
    deferral.Complete();
}
```